# TextInputLayout EditText gravity not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have started using `TextInputLayout`. I want the hint of the `EditText` to align in the center.  But for for some reason the hint isn't getting aligned to the center. However, once I start typing in the `EditText` field, the text is tetting aligned to the *centre*. Please help me with the proper alignment. I want my hint to be center aligned as well.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/dobLyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/dob"
          style="@style/MyEditText"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:hint="Date of Birth"
          android:inputType="number"
          android:textColor="#333333"
          android:textSize="15dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```